# Oracle 11 SQL lists and two table comparison

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of 12 strings (strings of numbers) that I need to compare to an existing table in Oracle. However I don't want to create a table just to do the compare; that takes more time than it is worth.

```
select 
    column_value as account_number
from 
    table(sys.odcivarchar2list('27001', '900480', '589358', '130740',
                               '807958', '579813', '1000100462', '656025',
                               '11046', '945287', '18193', '897603'))
```

This provides the correct result.

Now I want to compare that list of 12 against an actual table with account numbers to find the missing values.  Normally with two tables I would do a left join table1.account_number = table2.account_number and table two results will have blanks.  When I attempt that using the above, all I get are the results where the two records are equal.

```
select column_value as account_number, k.acct_num
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('27001',
'900480',
'589358',
'130740',
'807958',
'579813',
'1000100462',
'656025',
'11046',
'945287',
'18193',
'897603'
)) left join
isi_owner.t_known_acct k on column_value = k.acct_num
```

[image: result]

9 match, but 3 should be included in table1 and blank in table2

Thoughts?

Sean

Comment: Not sure... I just tried your code exactly as you wrote it and it works, producing the expected additional rows. (I used scott.dept for the "other table" and created a list of numbers '10','20','30',40','50',60' - just like in your setup; I got the first four matched and the last two unmatched, with NULL in deptno, exactly as expected). The code is fine; something else is the problem.

Comment: What about using the `NOT IN (...)` clause? This would be equivalent to an outer join, wouldn't it?

Comment: Please post the explain plan of your query

Comment: Found the problem but would like to hear any comments/suggestions for my learning...  Not given above was a where clause that limited table2 to acct_num(s) associated with a particular organization id.  Rather than ...where k.org_id = 1234 the left join should be column_value = k.acct_num and k.org_id = 1234.  This gives the output I expected.

Comment: @Sean the criteria in the where clause all need to evaluate to true. k.org_id is always null when it is missing.  To include the same criterion but allow null values you should put them in the `on` clause.